# Is there a way to unbind left-alt shift from "change input language" to something else, e.g. noop/do nothing

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, input-languages

I have 3 input languages (currently) on my laptop and I need all 3 (actually need 5), but hitting the alt-shift key is something I accidently do (a lot!), which changes the keyboard input language and if it is Cyrillic, it still looks like US English, but it isn't and it messes things up.

So, I would like to "unbind" that functionality.  I already moved the windows key to be in the upper left corner, thinking that win-space was the issue. However, being an emacs user, I need the alt key, so I cannot move that far away as it would defeat the purpose, and I have key combinations where alt-shift would be useful, so I just want to stop it from changing my input language.

I tried downloading the windows power toys and its keyboard manager but don't see a way in it to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't with the other hot keys, but you can fix it.

Open "Settings".  I have that icon on my taskbar, but it is also reachable from the "Start Menu".

In the "Settings" window's "find a setting" search box, enter "advanced keyboard settings".

In the settings page that brings up, click on "Input Language Hot Keys".

That will bring up a different window (mine was labelled "Text Services and Input Languages") and it has two tabs.  The "Advanced Key Settings" tab has a list of "Action" "Key Sequence" pairs.

Change the key sequence for "Between Input Languages" to "(None)" or the key sequence you want to use.

I found a method the above method here:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/how-to-turn-off-language-shortcut-key/40379a7e-b0f2-43f8-8335-ba634d4637be